# Using "echo" in a pipe in ansible's shell module

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm using the `shell` module:

```
- name: trust gpg key
  become: true
  shell: echo -e '5\ny\n' | gpg --homedir /root/.gnupg --command-fd 0 --edit-key 1401d4d21e93 trust
```

But this complains with

> gpg: cannot open '/dev/tty': No such device or address

The gpg command works when I run it manually. So the problem seems to be the `echo` into a pipe.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is caused by *pipelining*.

> Pipelining, if supported by the connection plugin, reduces the number of network operations required to execute a module on the remote server, by executing many Ansible modules without actual file transfer.

You can try setting:

```
export ANSIBLE_PIPELING=True
export ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELING=True
```

But I think you may encounter this caveat:

> However this (pipelining) conflicts with privilege escalation (become). For example, when using ‘sudo:’ operations you must first disable ‘requiretty’ in /etc/sudoers on all managed hosts, which is why it is disabled by default. This options is disabled if ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES is enabled.

To get around all this you may want to create a file for the trust and use the gpg `--import-ownertrust` command.

**Reference**

[Ansible Config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html)
[GPG import-ownertrust](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r1078.html)
[GPG import and export instructions](https://gist.github.com/chrisroos/1205934)